# PdfSharp Barcode 128 drawing on IIS makes symbols gaps

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, pdfsharp, code128

I need to draw barcode with code 128 font in pdf, so I'm using PdfSharp library. Barcode in pdf drawing like below:

```
XFont BarcodeFont = new XFont("Code 128", 40, XFontStyle.Regular);

tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Center;
XRect barecodeLabel = new XRect(new XPoint(leftMargin, rectanglesPadding), new XSize(page.Width - rightMargin, BarcodeFont.Height + 10));
tf.DrawString(PrepareBarcode(item.ItemNo_), BarcodeFont, XBrushes.Black, barecodeLabel, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
rectanglesPadding += barecodeLabel.Height - XUnit.FromPoint(5.0);
```

Preparing data for barcode:

```
private string PrepareBarcode(string itemNo)
    {
        int sumControl = SumControl(itemNo);
        string kod = "";
        kod += (char)209;
        kod += itemNo;

        kod += (char)sumControl;

        kod += (char)211;
        return kod;
    }
```

and sum control:

```
private int SumControl(string input)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (input[i] != ' ')
                {
                    int znak = (int)input[i] - 32;
                    sum += (i + 1) * ((int)input[i] - 32);
                }
            }
            sum += 104;
            int rem = Convert.ToInt32(Decimal.Remainder(sum, 103));

            if (rem < 95)
                return rem + 32;
            else
                return rem + 105;
        }
```

Font is embeded in pdf and the pdf is returned to aspx page as MemoryStream and flushed to browser:

WCF:

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document doc = new MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document();
                MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer renderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
                MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
                pdfRenderer.PdfDocument = document;
                pdfRenderer.DocumentRenderer = renderer;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    pdfRenderer.Save(ms, false);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    ms.Flush();
                    ms.Read(buffer, 0, (int)ms.Length);
                    return ms;
                }
```

And Aspx page:

```
try
            {
                zebexService = new SERVICES.NAV.WAREHOUSE.ZEBEX.ZebexClient();
                zebexService.Open();
                var wampirUserId = HttpContext.Current.GetWampirID();
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = zebexService.PrintBarcodeLabels(wampirUserId, itemToPrintList);
                zebexService.Close();

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Druk etykiet:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yy/mm/dd-hh:mm") + "_" + wampirUserId + ".pdf");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                stream.Close();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
                Response.Flush();
            }
```

When I draw it on localhost (windows 10, asp.net dev. server , lang. PL) it's drawed correctly:

[image: [Correctly drawed barcode in pdf on localhost]]]

but when I move code (WCF) to IIS Server with Windows Server 2012R2, lang. English with installed the same font (code128.ttf), I get barcode with large gaps between characters:

[image: [Not correctly drawed barcode]]

What can I do to eliminate this problem?

Comment: please check for any console errors?

Comment: Only:

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http://localhost:59384/Warehouse/Buffer/PrintLabels.aspx".

Comment: error is seen for the application moved to server?

Comment: Yes, but it's not marked as error. Just info.

Answer (score 2):

I can only help you by showing my code to generate a barcode ([EAN 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number)) using [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net) that works on both development and server. But it uses a different font: ean13.ttf, so maybe this won't work for you.

```
        using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
        {
            //create pdf header
            document.Info.Title = "My barcode";
            document.Info.Author = "Me";
            document.Info.Subject = "Barcode";
            document.Info.Keywords = "Barcode, Ean13";
            document.Info.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;

            //create new pdf page
            PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
            page.Width = XUnit.FromMillimeter(210);
            page.Height = XUnit.FromMillimeter(297);

            using (XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page))
            {
                //make sure the font is embedded
                var options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

                //declare a font for drawing in the PDF
                XFont fontEan = new XFont("Code EAN13", 75, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
                XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);

                //create the barcode from string
                gfx.DrawString(barcodeText, fontEan, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(15, 40, page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormat.TopLeft);     
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to draw index number like ABB302MOEL, so ean13 is not adequate.

Comment: I know, but maybe specifying the page with and height will fix your problem.

Comment: I've already do that:

`PdfPage page = document.AddPage();                        page.Width = XUnit.FromInch(2.76);
                        page.Height = XUnit.FromInch(2.07);
                        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
                        gfx.MFEH = PdfFontEmbedding.Always;
                        gfx.MUH = PdfFontEncoding.Unicode;
                        XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);`